# Kafka Connect not loading custom connector

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have created a custom connector which extends JdbcSinkConnector like this

```
public class CustomJdbcSinkConnector extends JdbcSinkConnector {

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Task> taskClass() {
        return CustomJdbcSinkTask.class;
    }

    @Override
    public String version() {
        //version of your custom connector
        return "1.0.0";
    }
}

public class CustomJdbcSinkTask extends JdbcSinkTask {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomJdbcSinkTask.class);

    ErrantRecordReporter reporter;
    DatabaseDialect dialect;
    JdbcSinkConfig config;
    JdbcDbWriter writer;
    int remainingRetries;
    private Map<String, String> configProps;


    @Override
    public void put(Collection<SinkRecord> records) {
        log.info("hello from custom put");
        log.info("custom put method starting...");
        JdbcSinkTask jdbcSinkTask = new JdbcSinkTask();
        jdbcSinkTask.put(records);
    }
}
```

and I have taken the jar build and added its path to plugin.path in connect-distributed.properties

Then started the kafka connect but this custom connector is not loading

The log shows,

```
[2023-05-30 14:54:01,585] INFO Loading plugin from: C:\Kafka\JDBC\custom-jdbc-sink-1.0.0.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:275)
[2023-05-30 14:54:01,613] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/C:/Kafka/JDBC/custom-jdbc-sink-1.0.0.jar} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:297)
```

It is loaded and registered but the plugin is not added.The jar file is not corrupted, I can run it from the terminal.

Comment: I don't think plugins are allowed to extend other connectors, only implement Connector interface... Note: You shouldn't put connect plugins as a subfolder of the broker classpath

Comment: I've tried extending Connector interface as well, but the log is similar to that of above. The plugin is not added and when listing the available connectors I don't see my custom connector.

Comment: Not sure, really. I do know that Kafka isn't well tested on windows, so could be related to the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom connector was able to load by using maven-assembly-plugin in pom.xml like

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.example.somedir.MainApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```